# How to open the current folder with other application option from inside of it?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, files

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I know I can click on any folder and choose *Open with other application* from the context menu.

When I am inside the folder, however, I cannot do that. I have to go outside of the folder and then click on that folder and then I can open it with other application.

[image: Nautilus context menus options]

Are there maybe some plugins or extensions for this?